# How to properly set up jenkins with docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, bind

I'm new to Docker and am learning how to implement Docker with Jenkins. I was able to succesfully bind a docker volume to my host machine directory with the following command

> docker run –name jenkinsci -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v ~/Jenkins:/var/jenkins_home/ jenkins/jenkins:lts

Now that the basic Jenkins is set up and binded to my host, there are a few things I wasn't sure to handle.

(1) This is only accessible through localhost:8080. How do I make this accessible to other computers? I've read that I can change the URL to my company's public IP address? Is this the right approach?

(2) I want to automate the installation of select plugins and setting the paths in the Global Tools Configuration. There were some tips on github https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md but I wasn't clear on where this Dockerfile is placed. For example, if I wanted the plugins MSBuild and Green Balls to be installed, what would that look like?

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

Would I have to create a text file called plugins.txt where it contains a list of plugins I want downloaded? Where will this Dockerfile be stored?

(3) I also want a Dockerfile that installs all the dependencies to run my .NET Windows project (nuget, msbuild, wix, nunit, etc). I believe this Dockerfile will be placed in my git repository.

Basically, I'm getting overwhelmed with all this Docker information and am trying to piece together how Docker interacts with Jenkins. I would appreciate any advice and guidance on these problems.

Comment: What do you mean with: automate plugin installation? Do you want have pre-installed plugins at Jenkins docker run? Also as I know, only NetCore apps are compatible with docker. .Net classic apps are just deployable in IIS. And IIs is not docker friendly. Are your apps using NetCore technology?

Answer (score 0):

Its ok to get overwhelmed by docker+kubernetes. Its a lot of information and whole overall shift how we have been handling applications/services.

1. To make jenkins available on all interfaces, use following command.

```sh
docker run –name jenkinsci -p "0.0.0.0:8080:8080" -p "0.0.0.0:50000:50000" -v ~/Jenkins:/var/jenkins_home/ jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

2. Yes, you have to provide the `plugins.txt` file, and create a new jenkins image containing all the required plugins. After that you can use this new image instead of jenkins/jenkins:lts.
3. The new image, suited for your workload should contain all the dependencies required for your environment.

Comment: I'm following https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md script usage steps on github. From the windows cmd prompt in my host machine, I created the plugin.txt (containing a few plugins I want to download) and a Dockerfile. These 2 files are stored in my host machine's Jenkins directory. When I build the build the dockerfile with the command "docker build .", the log shows the plugins are being downloaded. However, when I restart jenkins on my localhost:8080, the plugins are not downloaded...

Comment: It seems like I have to create a new container (with a new name and using the newly created image) to get my expected result. Is that correct? It seems strange to first create a jenkins container with the default config, manually create a plugins.txt and Dockerfile in that directory, build that dockerfile to create the new image, and then FINALLY create a new container with the new image. Is this the only way?

Comment: Nn, you dont need to create the container first with default config. Just create an image with your plugins installed or dependencies and run container from this image.